# Custom controls subclassing System.Windows.Forms.Control or UserControl?

Tags: .net, winforms

To make a custom control in .NET you can subclass the System.Windows.Forms.Control or the UserControl class. If you don't need to add controls in it, what's the best choice?

Thanks.

Comment: A custom control without any controls in it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest difference between `Control` and `UserControl` is that `UserControl` is designed to hold content.  It derives from `ScorllableControl` and `ContainerControl` and hence gets many of their capabilities.  If you want to add child Controls then this is the best choice.  In your case though you're not adding any child controls.  You still may want `UserControl` if you need scrolling but otherwise use `Control`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have your answer here ;-)

[Control vs UserControl in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921278/control-vs-usercontrol-in-winforms)