# Window vs User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Is there a difference between window and user control? It seems to me that these two are exactly the same. So which one should I use and when?
(I tried googling this phrase and I couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We make user control if we want to reuse it. As name says User Control it means some control like grid,combo box like that.If i need same grid on 3-4 windows then i will prefer to make it as User Control.If it is not reusable i will define my grid in the required window.At last you paste your user control on some window.

Conclusion :- If you want to reuse the control then make it as a user control otherwise define it in required window.

Answer (score 37):

A **[`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx)** is as the name suggests a **window**, it can be closed, minimized, resized etc. This should be quite intuitive.

A **[`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx)** on the other hand is **a composite component/module** which can be placed inside other controls and is itself made up of controls (possibly even other UserControls), the main use for UserControls is [reusability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reusability), [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), some applications can be broken up into a set of UserControls of which each one provides a certain functionality.<sup>[[citation needed]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

A window is managed by the OS and is placed on the desktop.

A UserControl is managed by wpf and is placed in a Window or in another UserControl.

Applications could be created by having a single Window and displaying lots of UserControls in that Window.

Answer (score 2):

wpf window is a Win32 window, but user control is just something of wpf, not a Win32 window.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you refer to the windows forms. Usually they are classified as user controls and custom controls - same stands for web forms as well. For more information you can refer to these links [control vs user control in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921278/control-vs-usercontrol-in-winforms) and [over view of user controls and custom contorls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667).

Comment: Uhm, no, it's wpf (Windows Presentation Foundation), so I think it's different?

Comment: The concept of user control and custom control is similar in WPF too. In user control you make controls as a composition of other controls and in custom control you extend an existing control. Its the same concept.