# C# build custom preview of completed form

Tags: c#, forms, build, report, preview

I am developing a C# project and I want to know what are the possibilities to generate a preview of the completed fields at the end. The ideea that I have is to pass the values from elements to some labels like that:

### Preview:

```
Name : Value printed with  Label1.Text = textBox1.Text
```

...
etc

I want to know if there is a better way to to this.

Edit: for windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ready made preview control for your requiremen. Probably you will have to create a userControl. A ListView control with two columns might help if you don't want to create a UserControl.

Comment: what exactly means a UserControl ?

Comment: Look at this thread. It explains Controls and UserControls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921278/control-vs-usercontrol-in-winforms